# PHP script that is supposed to hash a phrase but will output different hashes when the page is refreshed

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I created a couple lines of PHP to generate a hashed password that I can copy and insert into a report however if I press refresh on the web page the hashed password will change. Is it something I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
$hashed_password = password_hash('apple', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo($hashed_password)
?>
```

Comment: It's supposed to change, it generates a random salt when you call `password_hash()`

Comment: Is that an actuall password? Why would you need to include it in a report?

Comment: Thanks shows how good my college  lecturers are at explaining stuff. It's for a college assignment we just started and they want to see proof of our stuff working so I thought I could make this screen cap it put it in the report but the one stored in the database is not garunteed to be that one anyway which confused me

Comment: The whole idea of [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is to make a one-way hash of the password so it would be impossible (or at least infeasible) to reverse. So why you need to export the hash to a report I don't know, but if you add `echo password_verify('apple',$hashed_password) ? ' Correct!' : ' Wrong';` at the end of your code you'll see that even if the hash change when you refresh (As it should), it still match to the original password